# When mixing C and C++ code, does main() need to be in the C++ part?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, clang

I have a C program that I need to interface with a C++ library ([ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp)). Normally, it's not too difficult to interface C code with C++ code with a wrapper using `extern "C"` and using the C++ compiler to link, but I've never had to do it where `main` was in the C portion.

The [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#overview-mixing-langs) indicates that this is a bad thing:

> Here are some high points (though some compiler-vendors might not require all these; check with your compiler-vendor’s documentation):
>
> - You must use your C++ compiler when compiling `main()` (e.g., for static initialization)

But I see [another source saying it should be okay](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/mixing-c-and-cplusplus.html) these days:

> At one time, most C++ compilers required that function `main` be compiled by the C++ compiler. That requirement is not common today, ...

Why would it matter whether `main` is in the C portion or the C++ portion? How much trouble would I be in if I try to link code where it's in the C portion using common linkers today (mainly GCC's and Clang's)?

Comment: C++ requires that list of all static constructors is called before main(). The crt code normally does that when initializing, and that requires a C++ aware crt.

Comment: It depends on much your C++ code relies on parts of the C++ library that are initialised before `main()` (e.g. standard streams, such as `std::cout`) or makes use of statics at file scope (which, for classes, requires the constructors to be called before `main()`).   That requires, at minimum, the linking to be C++-aware (e.g. link against startup code for C++).   Practically, with some toolchains, since the compiler must emit code (e.g. to call constructors of statics) that can mean `main()` must be compiled as C++.

Comment: `main` is not the actual entry point where the host OS passes control to your program. That is usually a library function which performs the necessary C/C++ initialization (runtimes, exceptions, constructors etc) then calls `main`, and that function may be different between C and C++ builds. Which such function gets linked must be "negotiated" between the compiler and linker, and one possible way to do it is by "encoding" the target language into the object that contains `main`, based on the C vs. C++ type of that translation unit. Whether that's how it's done or not depends on the toolchain.

Comment: @Peter Hmm. C++-aware linking isn't a problem, but needing `main` to be compiled as C++ would be a headache. Any idea if GCC or Clang are such toolchains? So long as they work, it should be fine. But it sounds like I should probably start thinking about the best way to work around this.

Comment: I think this (needing to compile main with C++) was true of gcc 1.x and may have been true for 2.x, but anything more recent than that is probably ok.

Comment: Compilers are permitted to inject startup/shutdown code into main.  This is why recursively calling main is illegal.  As noted, this is not how it is done today usually.

Comment: @Dominic - Not sure about clang (never had to investigate this).  Early versions of gcc (up to version 2) needed `main()` to be compiled as C++.    I'm confident gcc 5 (dating from 2017) didn't require `main()` to be compiled as C++ for most flavours of unix and windows, as long as linking was done for C++ (e.g. using g++ driver).    I never had to check if gcc 3 or 4 would allow compiling `main()` as C and linking as C++.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to work around this is to rename your C main() and call it from a new C++ main()

As in:

```
// in ypur current C main module

int my_c_main(int argc, char* argv[]) /* renamed, was main() */
{
   /* ... */
]

// in a c++ module...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    extern "C" int my_c_main(int argc, char* argv[]);

    // if your c main() requires environment variables passed in envp,
    // You can allocate space for strings and an array here and pass
    // the environment variables you'll need, as the third parameter
    // to my_c_main(), or pass environ, if your system has
    // it defined in unistd.h

    return my_c_main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: The question asks whether `main` needs to be in `C++`. Providing a workaround does not answer the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  The Question is: "How much trouble would I be in if I try to link code where it's in the C portion using common linkers today (mainly GCC's and Clang's)?"  The consensus is that have a main() in C  could indeed be problematic.  My answer shows precisely how much troubel it would be.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Besides, maybe 2 or 3 years from now, someone will need this answer and arrive here by a google search. I'm not running after points, I've already encountered this issue in the past and I'm trying to be helpful.  I'm sorry for you if you don't dig it.

Comment: This is no doubt useful information, but @EricPostpischil does have a point... The question was "How much trouble would I be in," and the answer as written doesn't really address that at all. In my case, the C++ part is an optional module. Putting `main` there isn't really an "easy way to work around" when it may not even be there! Can I work around this? Of course, but it's not trivial. If modern compilers can cope with `main` being in C (as it sounds at least GCC can), that's a much preferred solution. That's why my question was what it was.

Comment: Well you could be in trouble immediately, or iin no trouble at all for years, until someone adds a cpp module with a nale starting with ab.  The best way to avoid trouble is to elude the question altogether.  When dealing with legacy code, you'd rather be safe than sorry.   I understand  Eric's point of view.  But he could have taken the time to post his own answer, or advice, couldn't he?